PHPSpreadsheet Scatter Charts not working consistently
I am trying to (re)create a scatter chart in PhpSpreadsheet but currently there are a few things not working. I do understand that not all Excel features are implemented in PhpSpreadsheet, but I cannot find a reference to what is possible (or not).
Assuming I have this input file:

there are a few things I want to achieve:

X-axis bounds should be 1 to 100, with major unit at 10 and minor at 2.
Label options should come from C2 to C5.
Formatting of title and axis titles.
Different colours for each marker.
Different marker type for (some) markers.

When I try to recreate the chart using PhpSpreadsheet using this code:
$reader = IOFactory::createReader( 'Xlsx' );
$reader->setIncludeCharts( TRUE );

$spreadsheet = $reader->load( $test_file );
$worksheet   = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$dataSeriesLabels = [
    new DataSeriesValues( DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Sheet1!$B$1', NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT, 1 ),
];

$xAxisTickValues = [
    new DataSeriesValues(
        DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER,
        'Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5',
        DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER,
        4
    ),
];

$dataSeriesValues = [
    new DataSeriesValues(
        DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER,
        'Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5',
        NULL,
        4,
    ),
];
$dataSeriesValues[0]
->setPointMarker('triangle')
->setPointSize(7)
->getMarkerFillColor()
->setColorProperties('F9DE69');
$dataSeriesValues[0]
->getMarkerBorderColor()
->setColorProperties('F9DE69');
$dataSeriesValues[0]->setScatterLines( FALSE );

$series = new DataSeries(
    DataSeries::TYPE_SCATTERCHART,
    NULL,
    range( 0, count( $dataSeriesValues ) - 1 ),
    $dataSeriesLabels,
    $xAxisTickValues,
    $dataSeriesValues,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    DataSeries::STYLE_MARKER
);

$layout = new Layout();
$layout->setShowSerName( TRUE );

$plotArea = new PlotArea( $layout, [ $series ] );

$title      = new Title( 'Test Relationship' );
$xAxisLabel = new Title( 'Variant 1' );
$yAxisLabel = new Title( 'Variant 2' );

$chart = new Chart(
    'test-relationship',
    $title,
    NULL,
    $plotArea,
    TRUE,
    DataSeries::EMPTY_AS_GAP,
    $xAxisLabel,
    $yAxisLabel
);

$chart->setTopLeftPosition( 'E24' );
$chart->setBottomRightPosition( 'M41' );

$worksheet->addChart( $chart );

header( 'Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test-output.xlsx"' );
header( 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' );

$writer = new Xlsx( $spreadsheet );

ob_end_clean();
$writer->setIncludeCharts( TRUE );

$writer->save( 'php://output' );

the output ends up like this:

From what I understand, I don't think I will be able to achieve 4 and 5, and maybe not even 2 and 3, but at least the bounds for the x-axis should be correct?! Currently, in the output file, the x-axis type is set to "Automatic select based on data" and I cannot change it to "Bounds". The y-axis is set correctly, so this seems inconsistent. This although the data references for both charts are the same.
Is there any way to achieve these goals, without having to manipulate the xlm? Is there something I am missing from the documentation?
A bonus question would be why the output file lacks the marker labels ...
P.s. Unfortunately I cannot attach my xlsx files.
